# I'm trying to convert a name input into numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a thing that changes your name into numbers and I'm not sure if I'm going about it the simplest or even the rightest way. I'm really new to programming.

```
public class Project1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    char ch1 = 'a';
    char ch2 = 'b';
    char ch3 = 'c';
    char ch4 = 'd';
    char ch5 = 'e';
    char ch6 = 'f';
    char ch7 = 'g';
    char ch8 = 'h';
    char ch9 = 'i';
    char ch10 = 'j';
    char ch11 = 'k';
    char ch12 = 'l';
    char ch13 = 'm';
    char ch14 = 'n';
    char ch15 = 'o';
    char ch16 = 'p';
    char ch17 = 'q';
    char ch18 = 'r';
    char ch19 = 's';
    char ch20 = 't';
    char ch21 = 'u';
    char ch22 = 'v';
    char ch23 = 'w';
    char ch24 = 'x';
    char ch25 = 'y';
    char ch26 = 'z';

    int num1 = ch1 - 'a' + 1;
    int num2 = ch2 - 'a' + 1;
    int num3 = ch3 - 'a' + 1;
    int num4 = ch4 - 'a' + 1;
    int num5 = ch5 - 'a' + 1;
    int num6 = ch6 - 'a' + 1;
    int num7 = ch7 - 'a' + 1;
    int num8 = ch8 - 'a' + 1;
    int num9 = ch9 - 'a' + 1;
    int num10 = ch10 - 'a' + 1;
    int num11 = ch11 - 'a' + 1;
    int num12 = ch12 - 'a' + 1;
    int num13 = ch13 - 'a' + 1;
    int num14 = ch14 - 'a' + 1;
    int num15 = ch15 - 'a' + 1;
    int num16 = ch16 - 'a' + 1;
    int num17 = ch17 - 'a' + 1;
    int num18 = ch18 - 'a' + 1;
    int num19 = ch19 - 'a' + 1;
    int num20 = ch20 - 'a' + 1;
    int num21 = ch21 - 'a' + 1;
    int num22 = ch22 - 'a' + 1;
    int num23 = ch23 - 'a' + 1;
    int num24 = ch24 - 'a' + 1;
    int num25 = ch25 - 'a' + 1;
    int num26 = ch26 - 'a' + 1;



    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name:");

    System.out.println("your name is: " +name);
}
}
```

Comment: A) no, as you already can see from the first answer, you are very much overcomplicating things. B) Please understand that questions like this ... actually do not belong here. Just posting code and asking "am I on the right track" doesn't fit here. This place is for specific problems, like "I am stuck exactly here, how do I this; or why does this here not work and give me that error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a much easier way.

Since you didn't say *how* you want to convert the string to a number/numbers. I will give you a few options to choose from.

First, you can use `hashCode`. This method returns a unique value for every unique string:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name:");

System.out.println("your name is: " + name.hashCode());
```

So if I enter "Sweeper" and "Sweeper", the output will be the same:

```
your name is: -143341447
```

Alternatively, you can convert each character to the corresponding ASCII code by casting `char` to `int`:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name:");
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
System.out.print("your name is: ");
for (char c : chars) {
    System.out.print((int)c);
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Entering "Sweeper" will output:

```
your name is: 83 119 101 101 112 101 114
```

Another method is to add up the ASCII values:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name:");
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
System.out.print("your name is: ");
int sum = 0;
for (char c : chars) {
    sum += (int)c;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

"Sweeper" as input will produce:

```
your name is: 731
```

You can also put a-z and A-Z in a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` to give each character your custom value:

```
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('a', 1);
map.put('b', 2);
map.put('c', 3);
map.put('d', 4);
map.put('e', 5);
// and so on...

String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name:");
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
System.out.print("your name is: ");
for (char c : chars) {
    System.out.print(map.get(c));
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Comment: For your second method why does it not print out the number that I assigned my int values to like when I put in n it puts out 110 and not 14?

Comment: @NicholasDrolet-Mercier it doesn't the second method prints the ASCII values. If you want to print your own values, try the last method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String name = "abc";
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
for (char c : chars) {
    System.out.print(c-'a'+1);
}
```